# No Mapping for GrailsDispatcherServlet in web.xml

Tags: servlets, grails

I used `grails install-templates` to create a `web.xml`. However I see that there is no servlet mapping for `GrailsDispatcherServlet` in this `web.xml`.

```
<!-- Grails dispatcher servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>grails</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>dispatchOptionsRequest</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
```

Intellij Shows an error that servlet mapping is required. However everything still works with embedded tomcat 7 server. How is this working?

Comment: Inspecting the web.xml in generated war, I guess it is done by `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter`. The web.xml generated by install-templates is not what is deployed to tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The particulars may depend on which version of Grails you are working with.  In Grails 2.5.6 the `servlet-mapping` is created by `ControllersGrailsPlugin` at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/bd7cc10e17d34f20cedce979724f0e3bacd4cdb4/grails-plugin-controllers/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/ControllersGrailsPlugin.groovy#L122-L125 where you will see the following...

```
'servlet-mapping' {
    'servlet-name'("grails")
    'url-pattern'("*.dispatch")
}
```

Comment: That is happening inside of `doWithWebDescriptor` which is where plugins may contribute to `web.xml`.